# How are inflection variance and invariance classified in linguistics?

Tags: terminology, grammar, theoretical-linguistics

I was trying to understand how variance and invariance in inflection is classified in linguistics. (Curiously I found [this redirect page on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Invariant_(linguistics)&redirect=no) but no dedicated article.)

What I mean is you can have [parts-of-speech](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parts-of-speech), you can have [grammatical categories](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/36413/what-is-the-general-term-for-linguistic-categories), but formally how would a property like inflection being variant or invariant be classified? For example, in traditional grammars number and gender would be considered categories but variance seems like -as some authors use it- a possible extension to both categories (you could have the singular/plural/invariant or masculine/feminine/invariant).

Comment: "property like inflection"?? Are you talking about word formation? If there is no variant, the word is invariant.

Comment: @Lambie read the example, how is variant/invariant classified in itself? Is it called a category, a trait, what is it called? And by comparison, there should be other such dichotomies that fall under a larger set with its own taxonomy. So what is that taxonomy? If derivation, composition are usually called "word formation"; categories of inflection are usually called "grammatical categories". Under what taxonomy would variance/invariace be classified (and what other comparable traits are there in that taxonomy)?

Comment: @Lambie this is a formal grammar question, in that variance/invariance in traditional grammars is mentioned but never put into a bag of comparable "properties/traits" (and the question is what would that bag of "properties/traits" be called grammatically, formally)?

Comment: First explain what you mean by variance / invariance. Don't tell us to read some other web page, you explain what you want to know.

Comment: I didn't find time to revise the question today, I will edit it soon.